# no suitable constructor found(Java)

Tags: java, arrays, object, aggregation

Trying to create object using aggregation but error shows no suitable constructor when using array to create objects. What I'm trying to understand is why wont the array identify the information implemented as I when I don't provide information on the object it is able to create an object with it's default information from both class' no-arg constructor

```
public class ComputerTest {
public static void main(String[] args){
    Computer c[] = new Computer[5];

    c[0] = new Computer("OEM", "Basic");
    c[1] = new Computer("Dell", "Optiplex", "discrete", "PCIEx16", 375, "8-pin",16);
    c[2] = new Computer("Lenova","IdeaCentre", "integrated", "N/A", 120, "N/A", 4);
    c[3] = new Computer("HP", "Omen Obelisk", "discrete", "PCIEx8", 150,"6-pin", 8);
    c[4] = new Computer("Lenovo" , "IdeaCentre", "integrated", "N/A", -110, "N/A", 2);
    printComputers(c);


}
static void printComputers(Computer c[]){
    for (int i=0; i<c.length; i++){
        System.out.println(c[i].getInfo());
    }

}
```

Using information from this class

```
public class Computer {
private String brand;
private String model;
private VideoCard VideoCard;

public Computer(){
    this.setBrand("OEM");
    this.setModel("Basic");
    this.VideoCard = new VideoCard();

}

public Computer(String brand, String model, VideoCard VideoCard){
    this.setBrand(brand);
    this.setModel(model);
    this.setVideoCard(VideoCard);
}

public void setBrand(String brand){
    this.brand = brand;
}

public void setModel(String model){
    this.model = model;
}

public void setVideoCard(VideoCard VideoCard){
    this.VideoCard = VideoCard;
}

public String getBrand(){
    return brand;
}

public String getModel(){
    return model;
}

public VideoCard getVideoCard(){
    return this.VideoCard;
}

public String getInfo(){
    String info = String.format("%s " + "%s\n" + "Video Card Info:\n" + "%s\n", getBrand(), getModel(), VideoCard.getInfo());
    return info;
}
```

which aggregates from this class

```
public class VideoCard {
private String type;
private String connection;
private int power;
private String extPower;
private int memory;

public VideoCard(){
    this.setType("integrated");
    this.setConnection("N/A");
    this.setPower(100);
    this.setExtPower("N/A");
    this.setMemory(1);
}

public VideoCard(String type, String connection, int power, String extPower, int memory){
    this.setType(type);
    this.setConnection(connection);
    this.setPower(power);
    this.setExtPower(extPower);
    this.setMemory(memory);

}

public void setType(String type){
    this.type = type;
}

public void setConnection(String connection){
    this.connection = connection;
}

public void setPower(int power){
    if(power>= 1 && power<=300){
    this.power = power;
    } if(power<1) {
        this.power = 75;
    } if(power>300){
        this.power = 200;
    }
}

public void setExtPower(String extPower){
    this.extPower = extPower;
}

public void setMemory(int memory){
    if(memory>=1 && memory<=12){
    this.memory = memory;
    } if(memory<1){
        this.memory = 1;
    } if(memory>12){
        this.memory = 12;
    }
}

public String getType(){
    setType(this.type);
    return type;
}

public String getConnection(){
    setConnection(this.connection);
    return connection;
}

public int getPower(){
    setPower(this.power);
    return power;
}

public String getExtPower(){
    setExtPower(this.extPower);
    return extPower;
}

public int getMemory(){
    setMemory(this.memory);
    return memory;
}

public String getInfo(){
    String info = String.format("Type:\t\t%s\n " + "Connection:\t%s\n " + "Power:\t\t%sW \n " + "Ext Power:\t%s\n " + "Memory:\t%dGB \n ",
            getType(), getConnection(), getPower(), getExtPower(), getMemory());
    return info;
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't automagically expand parameters into chained calls; if you want your `Computer` to take a `VideoCard`, you need to pass it a `new VideoCard(...)`.

Comment: Exactly where am I supposed to put new VideoCard() at the set method? Also am I supposed to put in the parameter or methods with it?

Comment: Your `Computer` constructor is `Computer(String brand, String model, VideoCard videoCard)`--note that at the end it takes _a `VideoCard` object_, not a bag of random values. Use `new VideoCard` there (with parameters) if you're wanting to create it inline.

Comment: So tried that but the parameters get an error stating that they can’t find symbol

Comment: Important lesson for programming: You don't get "an error", you get a _specific error_ (which you have described) _at a specific place_ (in Java, you get a specific character where the error was detected). Describe it if you need help.